# when trying to click on a jquery [+} tree via x-path in Watir I get the following error wrong number of arguments(3 for 1) (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby, watir

when trying to click on a jquery [+} tree via x-path in Watir I get the following error  wrong number of arguments(3 for 1) (ArgumentError)

```
When /^Go to e-Care and search for the policy created$/ do

link = element_by_xpath(String("//{0}[contains(normalize-space(text()),{1})]", "a",`enter code here` "Actions"))
link_parent = link.element_by_xpath((".."))
plus_div = link_parent.element_by_class(("expandable-hitarea"))
plus_div.click

end
```

Comment: Please simplify the code example and provide relevant HTML.

Comment: Are you using an old version watir-webdriver? I believe `element_by_xpath` and `element_by_xpath` no longer exist in the current version. It should be in the form `element(:xpath, 'path')` and `element(:css, 'css').`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing multiple arguments to String.new when a single argument is expected:

```
element_by_xpath(String("//{0}[contains(normalize-space(text()),{1})]", "a",`enter code here` "Actions"))
```

Examples:

```
String.new("foo")
=> "foo"
String.new("foo", "bar")
=>  wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1) (ArgumentError)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Watir, your step would be written as:

```
When /^Go to e-Care and search for the policy created$/ do
  link = @browser.link(:text => "Actions")
  link_parent = link.parent
  plus_div = link_parent.element(:class => "expandable-hitarea")
  plus_div.click
end
```

This assumes that your watir browser object is stored in the `@browser` instance variable.